# UIImagePickerController interfaceOrientation always come up as portrit

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am trying to capture the current orientation of the UIImagePickerController being presented, and changing the overlay view's `hidden` property accordingly.

```
if([notification.name isEqualToString:@"UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification"]) {
        UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = self.cameraImagePicker.interfaceOrientation;
        if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {
            self.cameraImagePicker.cameraOverlayView.hidden = NO;
        } else {
            self.cameraImagePicker.cameraOverlayView.hidden = YES;
        }
    }
```

However, `orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait` even if I rotate the camera, but this method is called every time the device rotates.

**Note:** My application only supports portrait orientation according to the project file, but rotation is somehow still supported by the UIImagePickerController

Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

After iOS6, apple changed the orientation API. you can try this method in your appdelegate,  I hope it can help you.

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application  supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```